# Why design by contract isn't more popular?

Tags: design-by-contract

In theory, it seems like a great solution for avoiding bugs, but why in practice we hear so little about it?

Why can't we see more support for it on Java or .net for example?

Answer (score 0):

i have been searching around for this answer too. But it seems like its not popular among the programming world. Therefore theres not much people discussing about it.
I tried using it, however i find it a hassel to really think what contracts i should write while i am programming. However its good for debugging.

have you tried? whats your comments on it?